# C# Changing Web Reference url

Tags: c#, dynamic, web-config, web-reference

I'm trying to change a web reference path depending on whether the site is live or not.

The application settings are in the web.config

```
<applicationSettings>
<WebReferenceName.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="WebReferenceName_Service_TBService"
    serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://localhost:50711/Service.svc</value>
  </setting>
</WebReferenceName.Properties.Settings>
```

I've tried the following:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.WebReferenceName_Service_TBService.Equals("http://www.newurl.com/service.svc");
```

which although doesn't error, checking it later, shows it hasn't changed.

and

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
config.AppSettings["WebReferenceName_Service_TBService"] = "http://www.newurl2.com/service.svc";
config.Save();
```

but this errors saying I don't have permissions

Is there another way of doing this?

I'd rather not have to use if statements all over the place, as my types are namespaced differently.
e.g.

```
using (var service = new WebServiceLocal.TheWebServiceService())
{
     WebServiceLocal.blah();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use config transformations? So a web.config and a web.release.config

Comment: It's so obvious when you put it like that! Sometimes you just can't see the wood through the trees. :-)

Comment: It's so often the case! I'll put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to do this is to use [config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx). So your default web.config would contain:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <WebReferenceName.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="WebReferenceName_Service_TBService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://localhost:50711/Service.svc</value>
        </setting>
    </WebReferenceName.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

And in your transform, you would have something like this (note the `xdt:Transform="Replace"`):

```
<applicationSettings>
    <WebReferenceName.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="WebReferenceName_Service_TBService" serializeAs="String">
            <value xdt:Transform="Replace">http://www.newurl2.com/service.svc</value>
        </setting>
    </WebReferenceName.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

A point to note, if you are doing something similar for an app.config (as opposed to web.config) you will need to install an addon like [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).